# C Fixed array pointing to parts of an array

Tags: c, pointers, arrays

I'm doing a project where I struck against this situation:

```
typedef unsigned char Page[16384];
unsigned char Memory[16384*64]={...values...};
void foo(Page* page);
```

Now as you can see Memory is composed of "Pages", now I would like to pass a Page to a function but a Page should be a POINTER to values of Memory (so indexes of a Page should be pointers to values of Memory). What I mean should be understand watching this:

```
Page tmp;
Memory[16400]=50;
tmp=(unsigned char[16384])&Memory[16384];//This is not possible but is what I would like to do
printf("Value should be 50: %d\n",tmp[15]);
```

Any suggestion?

**Update 1:**
I need that Memory is a big array and not array of arrays (while actually they are the same if I'm not wrong), it's a project requirement (for university).

**Update 2:**
Obviusly is a sample code, I used a macro for 16384 (and also for 16384*64), sizes can't change.

**Update 3:**
I would like to preserve Page as *unsigned char[16384]* because I would like to use it to pass values that should be stored (so they aren't stored anywhere) but I think it's impossible in this way so I'll follow [Tyler McHenry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/39375/tyler-mchenry) suggestion

**Update 4:**
As [Tyler McHenry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/39375/tyler-mchenry) stated, Update 3 doesn't make sense, so I'm explaining what I mean:
I would like to use Page to pass values to functions that must store those values to a "swap file" (is a system memory simulator), so actually there are some cases where a Page will not be a reference to anything (just an array of values), but the problem in this way is that a page should be a pointer to part of Memory **OR** just a simple array of 16384 bytes, so 1 type for 2 things is a problem.

An example could be this:

```
typedef char Page[16384];
void WritePageToSwapFile(char* swapfilePath,Page* page);
...somewhere in a function...
Page myNewPage;
myNewPage[5]=23;
WritePageToSwapFile("swapfile",&myNewPage);
...somewhere else, in another function...
Page tmp;
Memory[16400]=50;
tmp=(unsigned char[16384])&Memory[16384];//This is not possible but is what I would like to do
WritePageToSwapFile("swapfile",&tmp);
```

I don't think I can do both things with the same type

Comment: If this is a homework assignment, you should add the appropriate tag.

Comment: @Carl Norum: You are right I forgot it, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: re: Update 3. What you wrote doesn't make sense: "I would like to use it to pass values that should be stored (so they aren't stored anywhere)". Perhaps show a bit of code that outlines what you're ultimately trying to accomplish with the pages so we know what you're talking about?

Comment: @Carl Norum: Done as you suggested, maybe it's more clear in this way, sorry for my lack of english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the type of `tmp` to `Page *`, you can do this:

```
Page *tmp;
Memory[16400]=50;
tmp = (Page *)&Memory[16384];
WritePageToSwapFile("swapfile", tmp);
```

...is that what you want?

Comment: That's interesting, going to test

Comment: Here we go! That's the right syntax! thanks a lot... unfortunately it's too late, but I'm happy to know this, hopefully I can use this again

Answer (score 4):

Just have `Page` be a `unsigned char*` instead of an `unsigned char[16384]`, and you will have exactly what you want. The only caveat is that you will have to remember externally (e.g. using a constant `PAGE_SIZE` or something) how large a page is, since you will not be able to use `sizeof(Page)` to get this information.

e.g. (also making use of the `PAGE_SIZE` constant to eliminate the magic number 16384 sprinkled throughout your code...)

```
/* In C, this has to be a define, since I'm going to use it as part of an
 * array size specifier. In C++ it could be a constant integer */
#define PAGE_SIZE 16384

typedef unsigned char* Page;
unsigned char Memory[PAGE_SIZE*64]={...values...};

Page tmp;
Memory[PAGE_SIZE+15]=50;
tmp=&Memory[PAGE_SIZE];
printf("Value should be 50: %d\n", tmp[15]); // Prints 50

/* Print out all of the values in page "tmp" */
for (int i = 0; i < PAGE_SIZE; ++i) {
  printf("%d\n", tmp[i]);
}
```

Comment: On some architectures/compilers, this will bloat the size of the array beyond what is desired.

Comment: @San Jacinto Uh, explain how? The only array in question is `Memory`, and I'm not suggesting that he change that. The `Page` variables are simply aliases into the `Memory` array.

Comment: Nope, nope. You were right. my mistake. This is the 2nd time in 10 minutes I read a question WAY too fast. Carry on.

Comment: if the OP wants to select a byte at offset `o` in the page `n`, it is enough to do `Memory[n*PAGESIZE + o]`; of course 0 is the first page.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays as function parameters are equivalent to pointers. Just pass offset pointer like `Memory + 16384` to the function.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare array of pages:

```
Page Memory[64] = {{first page}, {2nd page} ... };
```

Still, this array will be isomorphic to flat-array.